# When to split data into train and test dataset

Tags: machine-learning

While creating a machine learning model, I was told by my peer that the split should happen as early as possible during the machine learning model building phase and especially before the data is normalized or scaled. I am very new to machine learning so was looking for some advice on that.

This is what I was doing

```
standardized_X = preprocessing.scale(x_data) 

X_train_std, X_test_std, y_train_std, y_test_std = train_test_split(standardized_X, df_breast.CLASS.values, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

Whereas I was advised that the sequence should be

```
X_train_std, X_test_std, y_train_std, y_test_std = train_test_split(standardized_X, df_breast.CLASS.values, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

standardized_X = preprocessing.scale(x_data)
```

Also, if you can please provide reasoning that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, both the training set and the testing test should be somewhat good representatives of the population (the union set). In many cases, this might not be the case.

The scaling basically standardizes the data by using the mean and the standard deviation of the sample. Often, the used formula is called z-score scaling [(x-mean)/(standard deviation)].

It is preferable to split the data into training and testing sets first, and then apply standardization to each of the set, using their respective means and standard deviations. If you standardize the whole dataset beforehand, then later when you split them into two different sets your model may have a bias. You can assess the accuracy of your model better if you have two different samples standardized with respect to their own centers and can have more confidence that your model will scale to real-life input.